# Change sysout logging level for Weblogic

Tags: logging, weblogic

When I run a local copy of Weblogic, I like to see the output in the console so that I can observe my app's logging messages. But, Weblogic spits out a lot of log messages I don't care about, like these:

```
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 08-29-2010 01:02:21 INFO Getting a JNDI connection
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 08-29-2010 01:02:21 INFO Connection Returned.  Elapsed time to acquire=0ms.
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 08-29-2010 01:02:21 INFO Getting a JNDI connection
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 08-29-2010 01:02:21 INFO Connection Returned.  Elapsed time to acquire=0ms.
```

Can I configure Weblogic to not output those? I assume that I can change the logging level to something higher than `INFO` and that should fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the "Redirect stdout logging enabled" option to avoid most of WebLogic logging in sysout. Only low-level (java/system errors) should go to system output.
I suggest to not use stdout (java System.out.println and related methods) to log server applications messages because the management of the resulting logs is difficult and system-dependent. Instead use ad-hoc logging frameworks like log4j, java.util.logging, Apache commons logging, ...

Answer (score -1):

You can try changing the severity as described here

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/logging/logging_services.html#wp1181596